# Locate a FEATURE on SharePoint root

Tags: 2010, feature

If I want to know elements of a particular FEATURE (any scope) before I hit the Activate button, I need to locate the FEATURE on SharePoint root.

I want to know what's the best way to locate the FEATURE on SharePoint root..with least amount of manual efforts..

Comment: I'm interested in why you needed to find the feature on disk. Can you provide some context?

Comment: That is to understand what exactly the feature would do once I activate it. This helps to understand how sharepoint does things nehind the scene and for learning purpose also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to open the corresponding feature directory based on title of the feature as you see on site/web features page from Site Settings:

```
Explorer (Get-SPFeature | Where-Object {$_.GetTitle([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture) -eq "Content Organizer"}).RootDirectory
```

Note that you will have to change the title based on the FEATURE that you are interested in..

Comment: That's the kind of thing I was getting that - though you've added a flourish of opening it in Explorer - Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to `c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\<Your feature name here>\`

Comment: I know the location where all feature are stored. But my question is how to I locate a particular feature. For example, on UI, I see "Content Organizer", so how do I find that feature on Sharepoint root?

Comment: because there is no such feature as "c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\Content Organizer"

Comment: If you have the ID you can use PowerShell to find out the Feature folder name in the 14 hive to find the folder. If you want to find a correlation between the "Title" as you see in the UI and the feature folder, there's a huge disconnect here, and it's not easy to do. If the feature is already activated, you will see the GUID of the feature in the URL when you're asked to confirm deactivating the feature, then you can get the foldername with that GUID.

Comment: Thanks for that info. what I notice though is it does not ask for confirmation for most features while activating.. they just get activated :-( ..  Anyways, I am close to finding the answer.. just want to get it done with least efforts..

Comment: Yeah, that's always dodgy, gotta be careful which one you activate as there's no prompt! I think there can be a way to do it, as if you do this: `Get-SPFeature | where {$_.Id -eq "ff48f7e6-2fa1-428d-9a15-ab154762043d"} | get-member` You'll get a list of al the available properties for that Feature, including a GetTitle method, but I don't know enough PowerShell to use that to build a filter on the actual Title. Maybe a PoSH Jedi could help

Comment: My thinking is you could maybe do somethign like `Get-SPFeature | get-member | where GetTitle -eq "My Feature Name"` or something like that (but I know that probably wont work).

Comment: thanks James.. you get an up-vote from me for the help and direction :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source of the feature admin page, you can look for the feature (i.e. look for content organiser text in the source). When you find the text in the page's source, in the same TR you can find the id of the feature that gets activated when you click the "Activate" button for that id. The id of the div around the button is the id of the feature.